# Replace patterns by a specific number in a dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need some help. Here is my dataframe:

```
   > df1
                  g_1             g_2      g_3     g_4  g_5
    species_1 canidae               0        0       0    0
    species_2 canidae               0 equidae3 canidae    0
    species_3       0               0        0 canidae    0
    species_4       0 leptodactylidae equidae3       0    0
    species_5       0               0        0       0 <NA>



  structure(list(g_1 = c("canidae", "canidae", "0", "0", "0"), 
    g_2 = c("0", "0", "0", "leptodactylidae", "0"), g_3 = c("0", 
    "equidae3", "0", "equidae3", "0"), g_4 = c("0", "canidae", 
    "canidae", "0", "0"), g_5 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "<NA>")), row.names = c("species_1", 
"species_2", "species_3", "species_4", "species_5"), class = "data.frame")
```

and the idea is for each item values such as `canidae leptodactylidae` etc to replace it by a specific number.

the number of items ending by ae is very huge in the real data.

So at the end if we say that :

```
canidae = 1
leptodactylidae = 2
equidae3=3
```

We should get:

```
> df2
                g_1             g_2      g_3     g_4     g_5
species_1       1               0        0       0       0
species_2       1               0        3       1       0
species_3       0               0        0       1       0
species_4       0               2        3       0       0
species_5       0               0        0       0       <NA>
```

If someone have an idae to do it in R ? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try with `match` `df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) match(x, c("canidae", "leptodactylidae", "equidae3"), nomatch = 0))`

Comment: @NelsonGon yes I know, in fact I suceed to do some steps in my previous question. So I juste deleted all these questions that I resolved and know I just cannot succed to do the mlast step which is about this topic I created for. But sorry anyway..

Comment: @akrun Thank you for you help, the problem is that I won't have a list of the names to assign a number, I'll probably have thousand of them, I cannot put them one by on into a vector.

Comment: You can create a unique vector from unlisting i.e. `un1 <- unlist(df1);un2 <- unique(un1[un1!= 0 & !is.na(un1)])` and use `un2` for `match`

Comment: Well in fact I found a way to do it with your code, tahnk you very much @akrun